# Downgrading from iOS 11 to 10.3.2 broke some core apps

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, bug, downgrade

So, impressed by WWDC as always, this year I decided to update my phone to the `iOS 11 Developer Beta` on my iPhone 6. After running the install for about two weeks, I decide that things are running a bit too slow - so I chose to downgrade back to `10.3.2` using [**this guide**](http://bgr.com/2017/06/08/how-to-downgrade-ios-11-beta-1/).

Using the above guide may not have been the right course of action - for now some of my major core apps have been broken/bricked, such as **Notes**, **News**, and **Podcasts**.

I reached out to [**@AppleSupport**](https://twitter.com/AppleSupport) on Twitter, and here is the answer they gave me:

> *What we’ll like to do next is restore the software of the iPhone. The restore process will erase the data on the iPhone, and install a fresh copy of 10.3.2. Before restoring, make sure you have a recent backup using iTunes or iCloud since the iPhone will be erased. After the iPhone is restored, let's setup the iPhone as new, and test the Notes app. Once confirmed that you’re able to use Notes as expected, we can put your backup back on the iPhone.*

The reason I am posting this, is that I am trying to avoid that process, and to also tell people that a quick reversion of the OS like how I did was a mistake.

**Does anyone have any idea how the Notes, News, and Podcasts apps can be fixed without having to do the whole backup/install/restore process suggested by Apple Support?**

Answer (score -2):

Downgrading to no longer supported (or supported but many bugs Operating Systems) may harm your phone
You have to return to iOS 11

Comment: Actually Seth, iOS 11 is prerelease and iOS 10 is the current release of iOS, meaning iOS 10 is still supported. Since iOS 11 is still in beta, it will run slowly and have many bugs.